# How to add a static/global variable in a single trait impl?

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust OOP, I have this trait

```rust
pub trait Animal {
  fn speak() -> ();
}
```

I implement two animals below:

```rust
// cat.rs
pub struct Cat;

impl Animal for Cat {
  fn speak() -> () {
    println!("Meow!")
  }
}

// dog.rs
pub struct Dog;

impl Animal for Dog {
  fn speak() -> () {
    println!("Woof!")
  }
}
```

Now, if I want to add a variable to **only** the `Cat impl`, like this:

```rust
// cat.rs
pub struct Cat;

impl Animal for Cat {
  const name: &'static str = "Felix";

  fn speak() -> () {
    // do something with name
    println!("Meow!")
  }
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0438]: const `name` is not a member of trait `Animal`
 --> src/cat.rs:5:5
  |
6 |     const name: &'static str = "Felix";
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a member of trait `Animal`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0438`.
```

Why can't I add some variables scoped to a specific impl (class?)

Comment: Nitpick: You can have just `pub struct Cat;` without parentheses. Also, please provide the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE (rust-analyzer has a way to show it now).

Comment: Have you read [the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/)?

Comment: Do you want a variable, or a constant?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman a constant, the question above provides example code in a simple format. I've processed the feedback you gave me, thank you. Regarding the rust book, I've not read it entirely. I mostly try to look up specific things for my use-case.

Comment: In addition to the answer below, an impl is not a class (the closest is structs, but traits are also related) and Rust is not OOP.

Comment: In fact, there‘s no OOP in Rust. Rust is more like a polymorphic mid-level functional language with low- and high-level capabilities. Almost every try to apply OO-pattern to Rust fails - not because Rust is wrong, but because there’s always a better way to implement something.

Comment: @Miiao understood, I just thought this was a good way to bind same properties with different implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have to do in two step

```
pub trait Animal {
  fn speak() -> ();
}

pub struct Cat;

impl Cat {
    const name: &'static str = "Felix";

    //.. fn new or other method
}

impl Animal for Cat {     
  fn speak() -> () {
    // do something with name
    println!("Meow!")
  }
}
```